# Pass Input Value with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to pass data of a hidden input through AJAX:
It's not a form, just a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" id="message-ids" value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10">

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'messages-get-new.php',
    data: ??????????
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Submission was successful.');
        console.log(data);
        $container.append(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('An error occurred.');
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

Comment: `data: {'message-ids' : $('#message-ids').val()},`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, use

```
{'message-ids' : $('#message-ids').val()}
```

The explanation being,

```
{'message-ids' //this is your key that ties to the value

: $('#message-ids') //this uses JQuery to get the element that has an id of "message-ids"
//The # sign is used to find something with an id that matches what comes after the # sign

.val()} //This simply returns the value of that element
```

Answer (score 1):

{'message-ids' : $('#message-ids').val()}

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

***use the below code***

```
data:{ yourparameter: $("#message-ids").val()}
```